# Node + express server: Firebase can't find default app

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm using firebase on my node server for my project. Before I had everything in a single `index.js` file, after that I decided to refactor and give some order to my code. Unfortunately, after doing that I keep getting this error:

`Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.`

Whenever I try to run `firebase server` or `npm run serve`.

This is my project:
`index.js`:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = require("express")();

const { signup } = require("./handlers/users");

app.post("/signup-user", signup);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

the file `handlers/users` is the following:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const { db } = require("../util/admin");
const config = require("../util/config");

firebase.initializeApp(config);

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  let userId;
  let token;
  const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword
  };

  // validate inputs

  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then(data => {
      userId = data.user.uid;
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then(token => {
      token = token;

      const newUserRole = {
        email: newUser.email,
        userId,
        role: "user"
      };

      return db.collection("users").add(newUserRole);
    })
    .then(data => {
      return res.status(201).json({ token });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      if (err.code === "auth/email-already-in-use") {
        return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already in use" });
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
      }
    });
};
```

lastly, the file `admin` is the following:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../../account.json");

const db = admin.firestore();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

module.exports = { admin, db }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the problem. In the file `admin.js` I was initialising firestore before initialising the app itself:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("../../account.json");

// This line should be moved after initializeApp`:
// const db = admin.firestore();

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
});

const db = admin.firestore();

module.exports = { admin, db }
```

Now everything works as expected!